# User CASE or subquery?

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables: tickets, tickets_users and users. My problem is that in the users table I have 2 types of users: requesters and solvers: type 1 and 2. 
I want to select the ticket, requester (if any, can be multiple) and solver (if any, can be multiple).

I'm thinking something in the lines of:

```
SELECT 
    t.id, t.description, 
    (u.id where u.type = 1) AS requester, 
    (u.id where u.type = 2)  AS solver
FROM 
    tickets t
INNER JOIN 
    tickets_users tu ON t.id = tu.ticket_id
INNER JOIN 
    users u ON tu.user_id = u.id
```

Obviously this does not work.

The tables look like this:

Tickets:

```
ID       Description    
1        Description 1 
2        Description 2
```

Tickets_users

```
ID        Ticket_ID  User_id   Type 
1         3          4         1
2         5          8         2
```

Users

```
ID        Name
1         John
2         Mary
```

Thanks,

In the meantime I think I found a solution using a sub-query in the join clause, but to me it looks rudimentary:

```
SELECT 
    t.id, t.name AS ticket_name, type1.users_id AS requester, 
    type2.users_id AS solver
FROM 
    tickets t
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT users_id, tickets_id 
     FROM tickets_users 
     WHERE TYPE = 1) type1 ON t.id = type1.tickets_id
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT users_id, tickets_id 
     FROM tickets_users 
     WHERE TYPE = 2) type2 ON t.id = type2.tickets_id
```

Comment: Join the table twice - or play around with MAX(CASE WHEN... THEN... END)

Answer (score 0):

Should be something like this.

```
SELECT 
    t.id, t.description, u.id, userType
    CASE WHEN u.type = 1 THEN 'requester' ELSE 'solver' END
FROM 
    tickets t
    INNER JOIN tickets_users tu ON t.id = tu.ticket_id
    INNER JOIN users u ON tu.user_id = u.id
```

Please provide sqlfiddle in case above example does not work.

With Joins,

```
SELECT 
    t.id, t.description, requesters.id, solvers.id
FROM 
    tickets t
    INNER JOIN tickets_users tu ON t.id = tu.ticket_id
    LEFT JOIN users requesters ON (tu.user_id = requesters.id AND requesters.type=1) 
    LEFT JOIN users solvers ON (tu.user_id = solvers.id AND solvers.type=2)
```

As you can tell, users table is joined twice (as requesters and as solvers with additional conditions). The reason LEFT JOIN is used is because if there's a record with no requesters or no solvers, INNER JOIN would completely ignore the whole record until it has a requester and a solver.

Comment: Thaks, I guess this would work, but it is not the output I want. I want to split the Type column in the users table in 2 columns: one for the requesters and one for the solvers. Something like this: TicketID, TicketDescription, RequesterID, SolverID.

Comment: I don't get the left joins? Which table is joined? There is only one users table and the users are either requesters or solvers depending on type.

Comment: Check the added explanation.

Comment: Just saw that, you might want to reconsider INNER JOIN and the fact that your sql has 2 subqueries + 2 joins which is a bit overkill for this task.

Comment: Agreed. Joining 2 sub-queryes will be very slow.

Comment: But there is a problem. Joining the table two times returns two rows for each ticket: one with the ticket, the requester and null for the solver, and another one with the ticket, null for the requester and the solver. I don't understand why?